# GUI notification list

Tags: user-interface, notifications, push-notification, javafx

Im building a graphical user interface of a notification list. i'm not sure how to implement this and how notifications would be displayed. Ive chosen javafx for creating the user interface. This is my first time creating a GUI. any help will be appreciated.